# For Revit Python Shell, does the message "Type "help", "copyright""... actually do anything?

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell

I am learning to use the Revit Python Shell and while I see the message below, it does not seem to do anything.

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I have tried typing all of the above words without quotes but all I get is error messages.

Can someone provide some insight on this?

Michelle

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, I assume that you have access to the entire source code, so you could look at that to find out if it is really important to you. For another, I would assume that the message you see is built into the underlying Python machinery that has been rearchitectured to run in the Revit Python shell, and that the messages refer to functionality in the original machinery that is no longer active in the new environment. So, I would recommend that you simply ignore this misleading message. If it irritates you very much, please research how to remove it and submit a pull request to the RPS repository to sweeten the lives of other sensitive persons like yourself.